# Determine the greatest common divisor of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $t$ is an odd positive integer I want to compute $(2t, 2t^2+t+2)$. What are if any the reduction steps or properties of the gcd that can help solve this?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400594/determining-if-two-numbers-are-relatively-prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yet another solution uses the fact that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-ca)$, where $a,b,c$ are integers. (This is why the Euclidean algorithm works.)

$$\gcd(2t,2t^2+t+2)=\gcd (2t, (2t^2+t+2) - t\cdot 2t)=\gcd(2t,t+2)$$

Flipping the identity around as $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-cb,b)$, we find that

$$\gcd(2t,t+2)=\gcd (2t - 2\cdot(t+2),t+2)=\gcd(-4,t+2)=\gcd(4,t+2).$$

Now, $t$ is an odd integer, so $t+2$ is as well. The last gcd must therefore be 1, since the other factors of 4 do not divide $t+2$. $~\square$

Comment: What made you set $c=t$? I am asking how are you setting $c$?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez: Setting $c=t$ in the first step made the $2t^2$ term go away.

Comment: Yes; it's polynomial division.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $d=gcd(2t,2t^2+t+2)$. Then $d\mid 2t$. Let $p\mid d$ be a prime divisor of $d$. Then it follows $p\mid 2t$, hence $p\mid2$ or $p\mid t$. If $p\mid t$ then we get from $p\mid 2t^2+t+2$ again $p\mid 2$. So $p=2\mid d$. But $2\nmid 2t^2+t+2$, since $t$ is odd. Hence $d=1$.

Comment: @user26857 Yes, right, I wanted to use that if $d\mid ab$ and $gcd(a,d)=1$, then $d\mid b$.

Answer (score 0):

If $d \mid 2t \to d \mid 2t^2 $. This means if $ g = (2t, 2t^2+t+2) \to 2t = gn, 2t^2 = gm, 2t^2+t+2 = gk \to g\mid (t+2) \to g \mid (2t-(t+2)) = (t-2) \to g \mid (t+2)-(t-2) = 4 \to g = \pm 1, 2, 4$. Now since $t$ is odd, $g \neq 4$, and $2t^2+t+2$ is odd, $g \neq 2$. Thus $g = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $2t^2+t+2=2t(t+1)-t+2$, we know that $\gcd(2t,2t^2+t+2)=\gcd(2t,2-t)$. Since $t$ is odd, $\gcd(2t,2-t)=\gcd(t,2-t)=\gcd(t,2)=1$.